# When we should have argument label in Swift function design, and when we should omitting argument label?

Tags: swift

According to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

We can design our function as

### With argument label

```
func someFunction(firstParameterName: Int, secondParameterName: Int) {
    // In the function body, firstParameterName and secondParameterName
    // refer to the argument values for the first and second parameters.
}
someFunction(firstParameterName: 1, secondParameterName: 2)
```

Or

### Omitting argument label

```
func someFunction(_ firstParameterName: Int, _ secondParameterName: Int) {
    // In the function body, firstParameterName and secondParameterName
    // refer to the argument values for the first and second parameters.
}
someFunction(1, 2)
```

Is there any rule-of-thumb, or best practice we should follow? So that, we know when we should have argument label, and when we should omitting argument label, when come to designing function?

Comment: The document you reference says “The use of argument labels can allow a function to be called in an expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a function body that is readable and clear in intent.” So, use argument labels where it renders that “expressive, sentence-like” syntax where you call it.

Comment: This question, as it stands, is too broad. There is no single rule, there is a set of guidelines. We cannot advice for a specific situation because you don't have a concrete example. Compare `add(subview: UIView)` with `addSubview(_ subview: UIView)`. The first one is too generic and would conflict with other `add` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of naming in Swift, you should check out [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines). These guidelines will give you a general feel of how to name things in Swift. Fair warning though, these rules are rather theoretical and at the end you are to decide how to name your functions in specific cases. Don't get too hung up on this really, even the most experienced developers have troubles with this, so I've been told.

In your particular situation you definitely shouldn't omit argument labels because type information is very generic and doesn't provide any clue as to what you're passing in.

Hope this helps!